I fundend an ETH smartcontract using .sol and remixeth.io but cancelled contract before withdrawing the coins
0xFcdA2700dCb5fb0f6CD0954498c922cDEbBFE32B
is there any way to get those coins back on my wallet?

Here's the etherscan link to the contract.
I can see 2 transactions of transfer function.
If you have any withdraw function on the smart contract, its possible otherwise sadly its not possible to withdraw the coins.
Let me know if you have any questions. Feel free to mark this as the answer if you find this helpful.
